# Rainbow Screen after Android Things installation

Tags: android-things, pi-3b+

I am new to Raspberry and Android Things. I have a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ and I am using latest Android Things (followed as per Android Developer Site). But why is it only showing Rainbow Screen after the Android Things installation?

Comment: Android Things currently is not working on RPi3 B+, just on the B.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49435727/3290339

Answer (score 3):

*Raspberry Pi 3 model **B+*** is not yet [officially supported by *Android Things*](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/index.html#hardware_platforms) in contrast to *Raspberry Pi 3 model B*.

Comment: Request has been raised but has stalled. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/76155541