# Flashing Android Things to Raspberry Pi 3 B+

Tags: android-things, pi-3b+

I have just got a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+. I initially installed Raspbian Pi OS on it temporarily to prove that it works and to prove that my touchscreen that I also got for the pi works OK.

I have now tried to flash Android Things image to the SD card, both using the console setup utility and manually using Etcher on two different SD cards. 1 of the SD cards is a 16GB class 10 SD card, the other is 8GB not sure what class though, both though are able to run raspbian OS.

However, when android things is flashed to the SD card, no boot attempt seems to be made. The red power LED comes on but the ACT light doesn't do anything. From what I've read this means that the SD Card is being read.

Looking at the SD card it looks like its not flashing properly but I'm not 100% sure. I've taken a screenshot of windows explorer to show what the SD card contains.

[image: SD Card Contents]

As mentioned earlier both SD cards can successfully boot from the Raspbian OS and when booting this image the ACT light flashes but nothing at all when trying to boot from Android Things.

Comment: @Ingo this is not a duplicate the question you linked references booting issues with raspbian, raspbian works fine for me

Comment: Please read the section `Other distributions`.

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/82293/70348

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android Things hasn’t been updated for the Pi3B+ yet.

Comment: I was just coming to that conclusion, I can't believe though that there's that much difference between the Pi 3 B and 3 B+ that would stop it working though. Are there any tricks to make it work even if its not officially supported, not been able to find anything so far.

Comment: `that much difference` the wifi is 2.4 and 5Ghz - so, that alone is a pretty big difference (probably a completely different chipset involved)

Comment: There's several hardware changes that would warrant a different OS image.

Comment: That's hugely annoying didn't realise there was that much of a difference

Comment: I agree @Boardy... I'm just getting into developing with the Pi and was excited to learn about an android IOT OS. I jumped into buying a new Pi 3b+ (for the better WiFi experience mostly) and then started doing my research. After spending a good many hours trying to just get something as simple as OSMC running on it I was positive that the Pi was defective! I just happen to run across a comment left by someone else that they had to use the latest release of Raspbian to get it to boot. I guess that serves me right for trying to stay on the cutting edge. Lesson learned, wait for compatibility.

Comment: I pretty much did the same thing, thought it was silly buying the older generation when the new one was out thinking putting a + in the name wouldn't make a huge difference to the OS.:(

Comment: https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/raspberrypi

Comment: @AnuMartin no mention of the Pi3B+ yet !

Comment: @CoderMike , my bad :(