# Does Raspberry Pi 4 Support Android Things?

Tags: pi-4, spi

I am trying to communicate with an MFRC522 device using my RPi 4B and the SPI interface. My application is written in Java and communicates under NetBeans with the RPi as a remote platform. The application itself runs on the RPi. At present, I am unable to read from any device register on the MFRC522 since the Pi4J and Spi Java libraries do not provide an spi.transfer command, the only means I can see of reading from the device.

I can see from some examples written in Python that it is possible using the transfer command seemingly available from the Python libraries, but the same command is unavaileble in Java.

I have also seen a Java application using the spi.transfer command. This seems to be possible using the com.google.android.things.pio.SpiDevice library, but I cannot find where a copy of this library exists to download a Jar file. I have also seen a comment that implies that Android Things is not supported on RPi4, but only on RPi3. Can anyone confirm this, or suggest how I could read using SPI on RPi4

Comment: The "transfer" command in Pi4J is called `wiringPiSPIDataRW()`.

Comment: The only RPi supported by Android Things is the 3B as explained [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/82293/rainbow-screen-after-android-things-installation)

Answer (score 2):

> Does Raspberry Pi 4 Support Android Things?

No, The [Android Things](https://developer.android.com/things/get-started) is supported just on the Raspberry Pi 3 Model B and you can not run it on a Raspberry Pi 4.

In [this link](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware), you can see which board/hardware is supported by Google Android Things.